# Why NSURL class exists? Why URL string is not used?

Tags: objective-c

I want to know why NSURL class exists. I think the code below is meaningless.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.co.jp/"];
NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Why the code below is not allowed?

```
NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://www.apple.co.jp/" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably because Apple felt there was enough justification for a class that represented a URL that comprised more functionality than just its _string_ representation. Check the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Aaron You really ought to submit that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: You're probably right.

Comment: Actually, if it's really really really important to you to be able to say something like `NSString stringWithContentsOfURLString:@"http://www.apple.co.jp/"` you can just add that method to NSString through a category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of Object Oriented Programming. Apple felt there was enough justification for a class that represented a URL that comprised more functionality than just its *string* representation. The documentation is always a good place to start:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice which is very easy to understand!